# Can I have multiple GitHub Actions workflow files?

Tags: github-actions

Can I have multiple workflow files?

I have a few repo's utilizing GitHub Actions and they work great! In my specific use case, I auto-deploy to my dev environment on "push," and I auto-deploy to production on "release." These are two separate workflows.

I know I can have these two workflows in the same main.workflow file and that would work just fine, but I would prefer to have them in separate workflow files completely. Would it be possible for example to have a dev.workflow file, and a prod.workflow file?

I have tried creating a dev.workflow and prod.workflow file, but they don't seem to be picked up by Actions. It appears a main.workflow file is required. If that is the case, is there a way to source other workflow files into the main.workflow?

Comment: Were your files written in **yml**?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since this question was asked, GitHub has made a few changes to workflows. They are now written in YAML syntax rather than HCL, and instead of being stored in a `.github/main.workflow` file, they are stored in a `.github/workflows` directory. The [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) says that "You must store workflow files" (note the plural) "in the `.github/workflows` directory of your repository."

So once you port your `main.workflow` file to YAML syntax, you should be able to store each workflow in a single file the way you wanted.

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276452/run-github-actions-in-monorepo?noredirect=1#comment127692674_72276452

Answer (score 101):

You can have multiple files in the `.github/workflows` folder. All files will be read and run as independent tests. The 'on' parameter on each file will tell when it must be called.

Following your idea you could have:

`dev.workflow.yml` - To run some kind of testing maybe (only on dev branch, when push)

```
name: Dev Workflow - Test and check thing
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
jobs:
  ...
```

`prod.workflow.yml`- To build and deploy your project (only on master branch, when a PR is closed)

```
name: Master Workflow - Build and deploy to production
on:
  pull_request:
    types: closed
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  ...
```

Comment: @ItsKarma I updated the answer to explain better for anyone that finds for a good explanation. :)

Comment: How do we know which **yml** file gets run first?

Comment: They will run parallelly if have the same condition, but not guarantee the order.

Comment: @TiagoGouvêa, could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276452/run-github-actions-in-monorepo?noredirect=1#comment127692674_72276452

Comment: In what order are those files executed?

Comment: @skan it will start all files at same time, or in a random order... to wait for a file to finish, to run another one you need another solution.

Answer (score -4):

Yes you can have multiple yml files under the workflow directory, and you can also have all of them have the same condition so they could be run parallelly. However it's not recommended.
as to the answer from [https://github.community/t/execution-order-for-multiple-workflows-in-one-repo/116780]

> Every workflow needs an event trigger defined in the yaml file, if your operation triggers the event, the workflow will be started, they can be in parallel.