# Run Github actions in monorepo

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a project which contains 2 folder: `backend`  and `frontend`. In each folder i added the corresponded project, each project has its own `package.json`. Also in each folder/project  i have `.github` with sett workflow/file.yml where is sett github actions for `backend` and also for `frontend`
EX: 1. `frontend/.github/workflows/file.yml` and 2. `backend/.github/workflows/file.yml`.`backend` folder is the root and `frontend` is located inside it. 
 Now if i push my changes being in `backend` folder i trigger only BE github actions, but i also need to run the `frontend` actions. 
 **Question**: Does somebody face this kind of issue and how to  run both github actions?

Comment: Can you how your current workflows ?

Comment: @Grzegorz Krukowski
 , Both workflow works, i need to know only if i can to run `frontend` together with `backend` workflow? Because now is run only `backend` being as a root folder.

Comment: The `.github` directory can only exist in the root. Others are ignored. GitHub Actions don't work very well with monorepos, but e.g. here's a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72252469/two-projects-in-one-repository-with-github-actions-monorepo/72268873#72268873

Answer (score 0):

You can run many workflows at same time, as you want.

- You must have a `.github/workflows` folder, where your actions will be;
- Each file must have a `on` clause
- Use `cd backend` and `cd frontend` to access file on subdirectories during the action
- You can add some `pwd && ls` to check if you are on right directory

It's enough to run more than on action, for the back and the front.